# Farseer collisions

Tags: windows-phone-7, xna, farseer

I am using farseer physics engine to detect collision between N boxes.
One of them placed at bottom of the screen. Others appear when you click on the screen. They appear on a strictly first compartment at a certain height. And when they fall on a box number 1 is a collision, but the boxes are behaving as if they were rubber (physics and not the image). On the screen it looks like a box falls through the second about half and then crawls on top of the box. How can I fix it?

Comment: And also they do not fly if the face is not exactly on each other and with a slight offset in the y

Answer (score 2):

I think your boxes have a strong restitution value. Restitution makes a body bounce.

for example:

```
Body body = BodyFactory.CreateBody(world, Vector2.Zero);

body.Restitution = (play with some float value.);
```

I hope this is the answer to your problem.